# Using multiple web pages folder with maven

Tags: maven, module, web

Im new with Maven and i want to migrate my framework from ant to maven but im stuck in a problem. This is the situation.

My project structure is something like

```
project
   module1
   module2
   ...
```

Each module may contain a webapps folder and an ant scripts joins every modules in a build folder with all webapps folders unified in one. I need this schema because my framework is one of this modules and it contain jsp and web stuff but there can be some other modules with custom stuff or extensions.

Thing is that maven modules does not fit because its no like module2 depends on module1 or parent "needs" this modules. Its like "i need to join all this splitted stuff together."

So the questions are

Is there a way to create a module exporting "web" stuff (not in war, just to join web content with parent project web content)?

If not, is there a way to split web content in several folders/modules/something so i can keep it modularized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WAR Overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) might be able to help.  Importing module A as an overlay into module B will essentially mean that module B gets all of module A's web content as well as its own.  You can also configure inclusion and exclusion filters if you need to.  Both module A and module B are WAR projects.

Comment: Great! i will take a look asap and confirm that this is the way, thanks!